# Equivalent of Spring MVC @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED) in Jersey?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jersey, jax-rs

What's the Jersey equivalent of this Spring MVC code? I need the response to return 201 along with the resource URL, following successful POST:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
Widget create(@RequestBody @Valid Widget wid) {
  return service.create(wid);
}
```

This is the shortest example I found in Jersey. Is it required to build the response manually for successful POST/201?

```
@POST @Path("widget")
Response create(@RequestBody @Valid Widget wid) {
   return Response
             .status(Response.Status.CREATED)
             .entity("new widget created")
             .header("Location","http://localhost:7001/widget"+wid)
             .build();
  }
```

Comment: I don't think there is an equivalent, but personally, I like creating my own response. I have more control. Also there is a `Response.created(...)`, then will automatically set the status. It accepts the URI or String as the location header. Also You can use `UriInfo` to `getAbsolutePathBuilder()` then just append the created id. That's generally the way I go about it

Comment: sounds interesting, can you post an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example of comment, per request of OP:**

> I don't think there is an equivalent, but personally, I like creating my own response. I have more control. Also there is a `Response.created(...)`, this will automatically set the status. It accepts the URI or String as an argument, and sets the location header with that argument. Also You can use `UriInfo` to `getAbsolutePathBuilder()` then just append the created id. That's generally the way I go about it.

```
@Path("/widgets")
public class WidgetResource {

    @Inject
    WidgetService widgetService;

    @POST
    @Consumes(...)
    public Response createWidget(@Context UriInfo uriInfo, Widget widget) {
        Widget created = widgetService.createWidget(widget);

        UriBuilder builder = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder();
        URI uri = builder.path(created.getId()).build();

        return Response.created(uri).build();
    }
}
```

This is the general pattern I use for my create methods. The collection path will be the absolute path obtained from [`uriInfo.getAbsolutePath(Builder)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getAbsolutePathBuilder%28%29), then you just append the created id to the path. So if the collection path is `http://blah.com/widgets`, and the id is `someId`, then the location header will be `Location: http://blah.com/widgets/someId` (which is the location of the new resource), and the status will get set to `201 Created`

[`Response.created(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#created%28java.net.URI%29) returns [`Response.ResponseBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html), just like `Response.status`, so you can do the usual method chaining. There are a number of static method on `Response` that have default settings, like `ok`, `noContent`. Just do through the API. Their names pretty much match up with the status name.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an annotation like that in Jersey. You could create one using [Name Binding](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9921).

Basically, you create an annotation and add the `@NameBinding` meta-annotation:

```
@NameBinding
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ResponseStatusCreated {}
```

Next you create an filter which will override the status.

```
@ResponseStatusCreated
@Provider
class StatusCreatedFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, 
                       ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        responseContext.setStatusInfo(Response.Status.CREATED)

        String location = "..."; // set based on responseContext.getEntity() 
                                 // or any other properties
        responseContext.getHeaders().putSingle("Location", location);
    }
}
```

Then use the same annotation on your resource methods.

```
@POST
@Path("widget")
@ResponseStatusCreated
Object create(@RequestBody @Valid Widget wid) {
    return ... // return whatever you need to build the
               // correct header fields in the filter
}
```

---

You could also make it more generic by creating an annotation that will accept the status as an argument, i.e. `@ResponseStatus(Status.CREATED)` and get the status in the filter using `responseContext.getAnnotations()`.

Comment: kudos for `@NameBinding`, learned something, trying to decide which answer to go with, this option is more upfront work, but certainly more elegant in use.